# sms response string iteration

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I have string receiving as follows, which is not a proper json string.

```
{"recipients": 1, "delivery_stats": {"delivered": 0, "bounced": 0, "responses": 0, "pending": 1, "optouts": 0}, "sms": 1, "cost": 1, "send_at": "2017-03-21 05:04:01", "error": {"code": "SUCCESS", "description": "OK"}, "message_id": 9579849}
```

And I need to extract data to check certain parameters, like code is equal to SUCCESS and also get values for `send_at`,`message_id`.

whats the best way in PHP to do it? can it be converted to a json string and iterate?

Comment: What about that string is not valid JSON?

Comment: pass it to the json_decode() function

Comment: a) your provided data **is** JSON. b) what have you **tried** so far?

Comment: sorry guys my mistake

Comment: I've pasted a correct json string instead of the one should have been posted. Anyway I've found the error and in it as well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

It's a json string. [Demo](https://eval.in/758095).

```
<?php
$o = json_decode('{"recipients": 1, "delivery_stats": {"delivered": 0, "bounced": 0, "responses": 0, "pending": 1, "optouts": 0}, "sms": 1, "cost": 1, "send_at": "2017-03-21 05:04:01", "error": {"code": "SUCCESS", "description": "OK"}, "message_id": 9579849}', true);

echo $o['error']['code'];
```